# MySQL : Is a key value in md5 encoded fast for a condition search?

Tags: mysql, key, md5

I'd like to have some suggestions from you. I'm going to build another table which contain a column of md5. One thing I'm thinking of is a search condition. Is it good to have the compare destination with md5 - ee321bb135275bca6c00bbcd14a3ae09, for example?

Example

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SID='ee321bb135275bca6c00bbcd14a3ae09' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

Regards,

Comment: as long SID is a key I suppose its ok.
But I do not understand what you mean with "compare destination".

Can you make your question a litle bit clearer?

Comment: I mean a destination of compare condition - where clause I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Add and index to the SID column and I think it should be fine:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD INDEX IDX_SID(SID);
```

Comment: I'm thinking about it, designing the table now... thnx.

Comment: the above code is SQL . I think sqllite uses create index syntax. Check it